# phpunit test method with static methods inside

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to mock `Carbon::now()` and `Transaction::where...` (eloquent model in laravel) with Mockery. Is it possible? I don't have any idea how can I do this when code is written without dependency injection

```
class SomeClass
{
   public function getLatest()
   {
        $cacheTime = Carbon::now();

        if ($cacheTime > 'xxxx') {
            return 'abcdefgh';
        }

        return Transaction::where('base', '=', 'asas')
            ->where('target', '=', 'bbbb')
            ->orderByDesc('created_at')
            ->first();
   }
}
```

Comment: What kind of library is `Transaction` ? Please provide a link or full namespace.

Comment: App\Transaction (Larave model). and SomeClass is service App\Services\SomeClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily mock `Carbon`:

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing

```
$knownDate = Carbon::create(2001, 5, 21, 12);          // create testing date
Carbon::setTestNow($knownDate);                        // set the mock (of course this could be a real mock object)
echo Carbon::now();                                    // 2001-05-21 12:00:00
```

So in your unit test just call `Carbon::setTestNow($knownDate);` before your function call.
Something like that:

```
public function testGetLatest()
{
    $knownDate = Carbon::create(2001, 5, 21, 12);          // create testing date
    Carbon::setTestNow($knownDate);  
    $someClass = new SomeClass;

    $result = $someClass->getLatest();

    ...
}
```

I don't think you can mock `Transaction::where` in your code and there is no purpose of doing it. The `where` and `orderByDesc` functions just setting your query. The `first` function will actually return the `Transaction` object. Even if you could mock or stub the `first` function, then your test is kind of useless because you are testing that your `getLatest` function returns some kind of mock object created by you.

This is actually a good example of integration test and Laravel provides a variety of helpful tools to make it easier. Check out this link:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#writing-factories

Comment: maybe you have some idea to create mock on eloquent model? im trying... and no effects